# How to call netlify function and pass variable within another js file?

Tags: javascript, netlify

I have an API that want to access whenever a user clicks on a certain state on the US Map. I’d like to get the state id (ex: CA) and send it to the netlify function.
The netlify function would then get everything I need from the API and return it to the client side js file I have.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What stack are you using on front end, may be I can explain better in that case.?
For now my understanding is just call netlify API on onClick method and then pass the id as params. This is a generic way of using 3rd party API.

If you want to know more in details, provide more information. e.g API url you are trying to use.